# Run jQuery code once document is ready AND iframe content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm experiencing issues with layout of my website as I am running some jQuery that gets applied once content is loaded / document is ready. However, it appears that because iframe content gets loaded in after document is ready plugin gets applied before that and screws up some layout of the website. Is there a method to only execute jQuery code once document is ready AND iframe content is loaded?

As iframe is generated by some plugin in wordpress I have little control and can't give it class name nor id. If you need to access it you can do so, like this: `.post-comments iframe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.holdReady(true);
    //init plugin
    $.holdReady(false);
    //other code
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what that does please?